# Got Null result from Oracle even though the real result are decimal value

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I am new to Oracle in Visual Studio,
I used *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess* as my reference,
The case is whenever I tried to retrieve decimal value from arithmetic in Oracle query, Its always return null

*e.g*
`SELECT 26/3 FROM DUAL` < ---- This code return null in my visual studio but has a value in TOAD.
Did I do it wrong ?

Here is my code to retrieve the value

```
List<object[]> result = new List<object[]>();
        OracleDataReader data;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OraConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = QueryString;
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    if (data.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (data.Read())
                        {
                            object[] itemData = new object[data.FieldCount];
                            //Dictionary<string, string> itemData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < data.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                Type type = data.GetValue(i).GetType();
                                if (typeof(string) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetString(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(DateTime) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetDateTime(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(int) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetInt32(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(decimal) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetDecimal(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(bool) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetBoolean(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(TimeSpan) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = data.GetTimeSpan(i);
                                }
                                if (typeof(Single) == type)
                                {
                                    itemData[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(data.GetOracleDecimal(i).ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            result.Add(itemData);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rows not found.");
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    data.Close();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return result;
```

UPDATED : It got null just for *division* which has decimal value. Addition, Substraction, multiplication has no issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data type doesn't match any of your `if` expressions. As there is no default branch, `itemData[i]` remains null. I suggest something like the following to find the gap:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.FieldCount; i++)
{
  Type type = data.GetValue(i).GetType();

  switch(type)
  {
    case typeof(string):
      itemData[i] = data.GetString(i);
      break;
    case typeof(DateTime):
      itemData[i] = data.GetDateTime(i);
      break;
    case typeof(int):
      itemData[i] = data.GetInt32(i);
      break;
    case typeof(decimal):
      itemData[i] = data.GetDecimal(i);
      break;
    case typeof(bool):
      itemData[i] = data.GetBoolean(i);
      break;
    case typeof(TimeSpan):
      itemData[i] = data.GetTimeSpan(i);
      break;
    case typeof(Single):
      itemData[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(data.GetOracleDecimal(i).ToString());
      break;
    default:
      MessageBox.Show("Unknown type " + type.Name);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response,  
But the errors occured even in this step
`data.GetValue(i)`
So the code even can't go further

Comment: Ah. You said `SELECT 26/3 FROM DUAL` returns null. I didn't know that it's already your `data.GetValue(i)` that returns null. I thought this method would always return an object (DBNull in case). Sorry, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got an advice to edit the oracle query
From (e.g.)
`SELECT 26/7 FROM DUAL`
TO
`SELECT TO_CHAR(26/7) FROM DUAL`

And **yes it works**

But still, I don't know why